# Sample TableView not print the array Swift OSX

Tags: macos, swift, tableview

I have the next code in my application but only print the next image,i don't know why.Someone who can help me solve this error.I think that the error is in the Dictionary.

[image: window without text]

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var viewTable: NSTableView!

func getDataArray () -> NSArray{
    var dataArray:[NSDictionary] = [["FirstName": "Debasis", "LastName": "Das"],
        ["FirstName": "Nishant", "LastName": "Singh"],
        ["FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Doe"],
        ["FirstName": "Jane", "LastName": "Doe"],
        ["FirstName": "Mary", "LastName": "Jane"]];
    return dataArray;
}

func numberOfRowsInTableView(aTableView: NSTableView!) -> Int
{
    let numberOfRows:Int = getDataArray().count
    return numberOfRows
}

func tableView(tableView: NSTableView!, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn!, row: Int) -> AnyObject!
{
    var newString: (AnyObject?) = getDataArray().objectAtIndex(row).objectForKey(tableColumn.identifier)
    println(newString)
    return newString;
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    }
}


}
```

Maybe it's silly but it's good to know how to do, I hope it will be useful.Finally my code works, the only thing he needed was set as data source.

[image: DatasourceViewController]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set the Identifier for the cells in the storyboard? If so then just get the row and with the identifier you can get the "FirstName" or "LastName", wich you return

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> AnyObject?
{
    var columnIdentifier = tableColumn!.identifier
    var newString: (AnyObject?)
    newString = getDataArray().objectAtIndex(row).valueForKey(columnIdentifier)
    println(newString)
    return newString
}
```

If you have further questions how to work with cell based tableViews: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingCellTables/PopulatingCellTables.html

Edit: 
you should set the tableView as Cell Based.
And i think you forget to set ViewController as dataSource and delegete for the tableview in the Storyboard

Comment: I assigned the identifier and implement your code but I've not been able to work honestly do not understand much, my way of learning is through videos and pictures, because nose if the link you sent me is Swift or Objective C, I would understand step step creating tables.

Comment: The identifiers for the cells are "FirstName" and "LastName"?
And did you set the tableView in the Attribute Inspectore as Cell Based?

Comment: Yes the identifiers are FirstName and LastName respectively

Comment: Sorry i don't understand you question. What do you want with println?
And you should google for a swift tableView tutorial, i think you should find many

Comment: the code is println and I want to see them in the console as it is done in Java or C ++ for the programming to see if the program is progressing well, but does not leave me any console.

Comment: And I tried to do the table according to the tutorial Apple but there are many questions that occur to me, so I tried using the storyboard but as you can tell not print anything on the table and despair me because I do not understand why and I do not find a sort of tutorial where I say this step is done first and then the other.

Comment: Now Apple tutorial I do not understand if you are programming in Swift or Objective C, I am very confused.

Comment: Ok you must set your ViewController as dataSource and delegate for the talbeview in the Storyboard.
The Apple Doc is unfortunately for Objective-C but the idea and the function names are the same

Comment: Thanks for your help @boddAh234 , thank you told me I knew that I needed.